# How to convert a strange date string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format

I have the following strange raw date format "**Apr rm2016 plan**". literally in the following format "**MMM** rm**YYYY** plan"

Is possible to convert it to a machine readable date format?

Answer (score 0):

You can translate that into [date style 106](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) 'mon dd yyyy' with a little string manipulation,

```
declare @d varchar(200)  = 'Apr rm2016 plan'

select convert(date, concat('1 ', substring(@d,1,3),' ', substring(@d,7,4)), 106)
```

Comment: what is this 106 doing here ?

Comment: 106 is the "Date Style" that tells the convert function what format to expect.

Comment: sorry if this sounds too basic. how would you apply in a query like SELECT [PERIOD] FROM source_TABLE   with SQL server 2016 where concat() function won't wok?

Comment: SELECT [PERIOD], convert(date, concat('1 ', substring(PERIOD,1,3),' ', substring(PERIOD,7,4)), 106)  AS ExtractedDate FROM source_TABLE

Comment: I get the following error: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.